# async streams not available in xamarin (C# 7.3)

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-standard

I am trying to add metadata to my Azure blobs (pictures) from my Xamarin app. I first tried this in a C# console app and it worked, but when I tried to put the code in my Xamarin app (as a new, seperate class) I got the following error.

> CS8370 Feature 'async streams' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

The error points to the first await (await foreach (BlobItem ...). I am using netstandard 2.0 (in my .csproj file it says < TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</ TargetFramework>)

I was wondering if i could change my code / change any settings to make it work?

This is my code:

```
static async Task AddType()
    {
        string connectionString = "xxx";

        // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

        // Get the container client object
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("raspberryuploads");

        // List all blobs in the container
        await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient("xxx", "yyy", blobItem.Name);
            IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // Add metadata to the dictionary by using key/value syntax
            metadata["Type"] = "Result";

            // Set the blob's metadata.
            await blobClient.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);
        }
    }
```

This code is mainly made up from microsoft documentation.

links: [Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) [Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: You could try either targeting .NET standard 2.1 or setting a language version in the project file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#override-a-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that you try to use a C# feature which is not part of your currently used version. You are using C# 7.3 which comes with .NET Standard 2.0. But you need C# 8 which comes with .NET Standard 2.1. You can read more about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8.
Try to upgrade your .NET Standard version to 2.1 and it should run.

Comment: Also note that this may be a ssimple as opening the project properties and CHANGING THE LANGUAGE VERSION. It is a property in the project. This allows one to limit the features available - which, in the OP's case comes back and bites him.

Comment: @Sebastian S. so i should just change netstandard2.0 to netstandard2.1 in .csproj file -> property group -> TargetFramework?

Comment: @TomTom when i go to properties -> build -> advanced -> Language version i can't choose C# 8.0, it says Automatically selected based on framework version

Comment: Yes, I would give it a try. I am pretty sure you are able to select C#8.0 like @TomTom mentioned after you upgraded to netstandard2.1

Comment: @SebastianS. thanks, the error is now gone, altough im still not able to change my language version. Last question, do i know this is safe and will not result in more errors later on?

Comment: @Fooourier I never had issues when upgrading from netstandard2.0 to 2.1. But this does not mean you will not have any issues. So I cannot give you a promise about that. Maybe you are using any Nuget package or anything else which have issues with netstandard2.1, you need to test it.

Comment: @SebastianS. thanks a lot!!!